# std::bad_alloc when storing single characters from a text file into a vector C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector, stdvector, bad-alloc

So my goal is to reading in and store single characters from a file (they're genome sequences). The files are very large and basically look something like this:

```
>gi|188033402|emb|CU859091.1| A BAC library has been constructed from PN40024...
AGCTCCTTTTTAAAACAACATTCAAGAAATTGGAGTTTGGCATTTTTACAAAGAGCATATTCAGCTCTGG
GAAGTATTTCTTGAGCAAAGAGGAGCGAAAATAGATCCTAAATGTTCCCCAGATTTTCCCCAGATTCCAA
```

Lines that begin with the " > " character can be completely ignored. So basically I just want the "AGCTCCTTTTTA..." part.

My code works fine for smaller files but crashes with much larger files. I'm trying to figure out what's the memory problem here and how I can solve it. The error I'm getting when I run the file is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
   what(): std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here's my simplified code for reading in the single characters and storing them into a vector:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   ifstream file (argv[1]);

   vector<char> sequenceA; // to store the single characters
   string line; // to grab lines from the file
   char c; // to grab the single character from the file

   // go through the file
   while(getline(file,line))
   {
      //store the line
      stringstream stream(line);

      // go through and grab each single character in the line
      while(stream.get(c))
      {
         if(c == '>')
         {
            // break and continue to the next line
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            // add the character to the list
            sequenceA.push_back(c);
         }
      }
   }
```

I was looking through other "std::bad_alloc" posts on stackoverflow, but couldn't seem to find one that helped me solve my issue, so your help would really be appreciated! If you couldn't tell, I'm still pretty new to programming and would appreciate your explanations.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You never mentioned how large these files are.

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to how big you can get before the exception? Optimization: With a bit of work you can pull `if(c == '>')` out of the while loop. something like `if (line.size() && line[0] != '>') { /* stringstream etc... */ }` right after the `while(getline(file,line)`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry about that! Unfortunately I don't know the exact size of the files... all I know is that if you try to print them to the console, you'll be waiting for a couple minutes for it to finish. Large enough for memory to be a problem it seems. Sorry I can't give you more details.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the optimization tip! I'll try to clean up my code. Also, I'm not sure how big I get before the exception... Is there a way for me to find out? (sorry if that's a silly question, I'm trying my best haha...)

Comment: Just increment a counter and surround your code with a `try / catch`.  When the `catch` occurs, then inspect the counter.

Comment: If `vector::push_back` fails, the `vector` is untouched. Catch the exception and print `sequenceA.length()` then maybe rethrow or do something creative to try and recover. Note this tells you where you hit a resize you couldn't get, not the actual limit. might also be worth printing the results of `stat` to see now big the file is.

Comment: _I don't know the exact size of files..._ Can't you do `ls -l`?

Comment: @Nichiren Also you should `sequenceA.insert(sequenceA.end(), line.begin(), line.end())`

Comment: @Nichiren -- Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit program?  If it's 32-bit, consider making this a 64-bit program, as the amount of memory that you can allocate is vastly more for 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the program is eventually asking for a contiguous block of memory large enough that the system can't provide it.

If you insist on your approach, a quick fix would probably be to use `deque` instead of `vector`.